# Is it possible to hide Quicksilver from the application switcher in Mac OS X v10.7 (Lion)?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

[Quicksilver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_%28software%29) is a background application, and I would prefer if it didn't show up in the application switcher when I press Command + Tab. Is it possible to hide applications from showing up in the application switcher?

It appears the [Finder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_%28software%29) is also always in the application switcher that I would rather not see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not that hard to do. From *Preferences » Application*, disable "Show icon in dock".

[image]

This will make it accessible through the menu bar:

[image]

Comment: Oh I thought that would just affect the dock at the bottom. Thanks. I don't suppose you know if I can get the Finder to also not show up on the command+tab? It doesn't seem to have a similar option.

Comment: @KitSunde Hm, the Finder? Not likely, would probably involve some major hacking. What you can however do is try out [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/), it allows you to hide certain apps from the switcher and generally has some neat features.